# How do you Play an MP3 in VB.NET and Determine MS Played?

Tags: vb.net

I need to play an MP3 in the background while generating animation.  The audio drives the animation timeline so I have to track MS from the start of the file to keep things in sync.  In VB6 I used the MMControl which raised an event at certain intervals and could count the frames from the beginning to always determine my position.  Just can not figure out the .Net way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the MMControl in VB6 was just a COM object, I would recommend using this same object since it worked for you in the past.

The following article seems to show how to do this:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/xxxpluto/MultimediaControls11182005001632AM/MultimediaControls.aspx

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks,

Found this on MicroSofts site on declaring the com object in code behind.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb262248(VS.85).aspx

Looks like the simple way to solve the problem.  Guess I was looking to hard for a .Net solution.

Comment: Cool, cool.  Good find.  I may be interested in building something with that just too see it in action.